# How can i delete data from my Firebase and update my table?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making a schedule for trains, the information is coming straight from user input. The user input gets stored in to my Firebase, as well as getting displayed in to a table. Each row of information has a delete button. When you click on the delete button, I am trying to delete the data from my Firebase along with updating the table.

Here is where I pushed the train information to my Firebase:

```
 database.ref().push({
      name: name,
      dest: dest,
      time: time,
      freq: freq,
      minutesAway: mins,
      dateAdded: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
    })
```

And then i have it displayed like this:

```
 $('.table').append('<tr><td>' + name +
    '</td>' + '<td>' + dest +
    '</td>' + '<td>' + time +
    '</td>' + '<td>' + freq +
    '</td>' + '<td>' + mins +
    '</td>' + '<td>' + '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm delete"></button>' +
    '</td>' + '</tr>');
```

Here is my onClick delete:

```
$(".delete").on("click", function () {
    $(this).parent().prevAll().parent().remove();

  });
```

And this is what my current Firebase tree looks like:

```
https://mavs-firebase.firebaseio.com/
mavs-firebase
-L7p60IRXp29D54Pk3dw
dateAdded: 
1521309455658
dest: 
"North Pole"
freq: 
"200"
minutesAway: 
122
name: 
"Polar Express"
time: 
"12:59"
```

I have been trying many different ways to find a function that deletes the data from Firebase and from the table, I cannot find a solution anywhere i look. I have even researched Firebase docs and i can't seem to target the right table and/or delete the data.

Answer (score 3):

To remove data from the database, lets say you want to target this `-L7p60IRXp29D54Pk3dw`, you can try the following:

```
var database = firebase.database();
var del=database.ref().child("-L7p60IRXp29D54Pk3dw").remove();
```

this will remove the all the child under the above key.

Comment: But if the user is creating a new child with a random character name every time they add a new train, how would i target that child that they created? i wouldn't want to add that code in every time someone adds a new train

Comment: each row has a delete button, so when the user clicks delete just pass the `key` inside the `child()`

Comment: sorry i didn't ask you my question right, i meant that when the user inputs a new train, it creates a new key. meaning each row i n the table has a different key, how would i basically target that "key" when the user clicks on the delete button?

Comment: when the user clicks the delete button, retrieve the data of that record, do orderbychild(...).equalTo(..).on() and you will be able to get the key and then use the key that you get to delete the record.

Comment: Yes! thank you for taking your time to help me, i dug super deep in my console and found out that each child's key is logged in to the console. I targeted the Key with a variable.

Comment: Okay since the answer helped you,  please mark it as correct,  thank you